# How do I click on an item on my google search page with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

## Good time of the day!

Faced with a seemingly simple problem,
But it’s been a while, and I’m asking for your help.
I work with Selenium on Python and I need to curse about
20 items on google search page by random request.
And I’ll give you an example of the elements below, and the bottom line is, once the elements are revealed,
Google generates new such elements

### Problem:

**Cannot click on the element. I will need to click on existing and then on new, generated elements in this block: [click for open see blocks with element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoc96.png)**

**Tried to click on xpath, having collected all the elements:**

```
xpath = '//*[@id="qmCCY_adG4Sj3QP025p4__16"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]'
all_elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=xpath)
for element in all_elements:
    element.click()
    sleep(2)
```

> Important note!
> id xpath has constantly changing and is generated by another on the google side

**Tried to click on the class**
`class="r21Kzd"`

**Tried to click on the selector:**
`#qmCCY_adG4Sj3QP025p4__16 > div > div > div > div.wWOJcd > div.r21Kzd`

### Errors

**This is when I try to click using xpath:**
`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector"://*[@id="vU-CY7u3C8PIrgTuuJH4CQ_9"]/div/div[1]/div[4]}`

*In other cases, the story is almost the same, the driver does not find the element and cannot click on it. Below I apply a scratch tag on which I need to click*
[screenshot tags on google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnaqX.png)

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: Can you share a **link** to that page? Pictures of GUI are absolutely not relevant here

Comment: `qmCCY_adG4Sj3QP025p4__16` probably a **dynamic** value

Comment: @Prophet Yep, it`s **dynamic** value. Google **generate random**

Comment: So, you have to find fixed locator, not based on dynamically changing values

Comment: @Prophet Sure, [google-search-page](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+coocking+rise%3F&oq=How+coocking+rise%3F&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i13i30j0i8i13i30l8.5537j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It`s template question on google-search

Comment: OK, and what are you trying to do there, what element to locate?

Comment: @Prophet So, I was looking for a locked locator, but selenium don`t want click him. I get exception like that in my question

Comment: Please add all this into your question. Clarify what element you want to click etc

Comment: This is fixed class `class="r21Kzd"`, I clicked him `driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, value='r21Kzd')` and get exception `no such element`

Comment: Because that element contains more classes, not only this

Comment: @Prophet I trying `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value=class_name)` and give value `iDjcJe IX9Lgd wwB5gf`. It is fixed class name for this. But i have exception `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".iDjcJe IX9Lgd wwB5gf"}`

Answer (score 0):

In case `iDjcJe IX9Lgd wwB5gf` are a fixed class name values of that element all you need is to use `CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `CLASS_NAME` with a correct syntax of CSS Selectors.
So, instead of `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "iDjcJe IX9Lgd wwB5gf")` try using this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".iDjcJe.IX9Lgd.wwB5gf")
```

(dots before each class name, no spaces between them)

Comment: I think your option might work otherwise, I did research this problem again and noticed that I use [pypi webdriver_manager](https:///pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) and user-agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 8.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.2039.82 Safari/537.34` and I have another page layout where there is only one class by which I can click `driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, value='xpc')`

Comment: I think I need a user-agent of one category, because I use random